# redirect rule with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I 'm searching a way to redirect

`/threads/2486-dell-inspiron-545-grafikkarte-austauschen/3page` to

```
threads/2486-dell-inspiron-545-grafikkarte-austauschen/page3
```

and I have been starting the write the rule but I'm not sure if is the right way to do it or not

```
RewriteRule ^threads/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$page  /threads/$1-$2/page$3 [R,L]
```

Comment: Did you try your own regex? is it working?

Comment: I've been trying out is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to modify your regex.

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/threads/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)page$ /threads/$1-$2/page$3
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?threads/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)page$ /threads/$1-$2/page$3 [L,R=301]
```

Note that you'll want to put the rewrite rule above any other routing rules you may have in your htaccess file, as you want this to be applied before the URI gets handled or routed. Also if you have a mix between mod_alias redirects and mod_rewrite routing, you may want to just stick with mod_rewrite.

Comment: thanks a lot it seems to work now most of the links, but I have some problems with those what containing special charachters ex. threads/1843-unbekanntes-ger%E4t-im-ger%E4temanager/2page

Comment: @user1659575 Then change the expression `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` to `([^/]+?)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Redirect 301 /threads/2486-dell-inspiron-545-grafikkarte-austauschen/3page /threads/2486-dell-inspiron-545-grafikkarte-austauschen/page3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the third group, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/threads/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)page  /threads/$1-$2/page$3 [R,L]
```

Trying to be more wide

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/threads/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)page  $1/threads/$2-$3/page$4 [R,L]
```

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/T8QtAV6kG5) the regex is working, notice that the `/` are escaped.

Comment: Substitute ^threads with threads (or ^/threads), ^ is the beginning of the line, if you have this the regex won't match any url but the ones starting with threads (eg no http://www.something.com/threads)